# Streaming MP3/AAC in Flash over HTTP

Tags: flash, streaming, audio-streaming, random-access, pseudo-streaming

I need to be able to play MP3/AAC audio with a custom-built Flash player, embedded in a web page using my standard HTTP server.

The loadSound() method seems to work fine for this, but I need to be able to skip the MP3 to unbuffered regions of the audio timeline and to start it streaming/downloading from there.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

I've used the excellent mod_h264_streaming plugin for Apache for f4v "pseudostreaming" so I'm trying to accomplish the same thing on my audio files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is by adding a Range argument to a GET request. The problem with this is that inside FlashPlayer custom headers are savaged...

I wrote this helper code a little while ago: http://code.google.com/p/redherring/

The idea being, proxy your request headers via the GET resource or POST data part of a request and have your server make the request the way it was intended.